# Define getter on object so all undefined property lookups return ""

Tags: javascript, node.js

Basically I need to be able to do this:

```
var obj = {"foo":"bar"},
    arr = [];
with( obj ){
   arr.push( foo );
   arr.push( notDefinedOnObj ); // fails with 'ReferenceError: notDefinedOnObj is not defined'
}
console.log(arr); // ["bar", ""] <- this is what it should be.
```

I'm looking for a "global" equivalent of [`{}.__defineGetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/DefineGetter)  or [{get}](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/get) in order to return an empty string for all undefined property getters (note that this is different than a property that is `undefined`).

Comment: Can you use a [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)?

Comment: It doesn't look like `Proxy` is available in any node version. :-(

Comment: Yeah. Looks like V8 is [still working on it](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1543).

Comment: `Proxy` is available on 0.7.8 with the --harmony command line flag.

Comment: And (a buggy) `Proxy` is available in node 0.6.18 via the `--harmony_proxies` flag.

Comment: Proxies work, btw. If you want to add your comment as an answer I'll accept it and then edit to add the code to do everything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to return an empty string whenever undefined properties are accessed.

`app.js`:

```
var obj = {"foo":"bar"},
    arr = [],
    p = Proxy.create({
        get: function(proxy, name) {
            return obj[name] === undefined ? '' : obj[name];
        }
    });
arr.push( p.foo );
arr.push( p.notDefinedOnObj );

console.log(arr);
```

As question author David Murdoch notes, if you are using node v0.6.18 (the latest stable release at the time this post was written), you must pass the `--harmony_proxies` option when you run the script:

```
$ node --harmony_proxies app.js
[ 'bar', '' ]
```

Note that this solution will **not** work if you use `with`, as in:

```
var obj = {"foo":"bar"},
    arr = [],
    p = Proxy.create({
        get: function(proxy, name) {
            return obj[name] === undefined ? '' : obj[name];
        }
    });
with ( p ) {
   arr.push( foo ); // ReferenceError: foo is not defined
   arr.push( notDefinedOnObj );
}

console.log(arr);
```

`with` does not seem to call the proxy's `get` method when adding the proxy to the scope chain.

Note: the proxy handler passed to `Proxy.create()` in this is example is *incomplete*. See [Proxy: Common mistakes and misunderstanding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy#Common_mistakes_and_misunderstanding) for more details.

Comment: The different proxy implementations are all over the place. Proxy in 0.6.x just doesn't work if you actually want to pass the proxy around. In 0.7.8 `Object.getPropertyDescriptor` doesn't exist, even though the `getPropertyDescriptor` method is required on the Proxy and gets called when you look up a non-existent property (you can fake it by using `Object.get**Own**PropertyDescriptor` instead).

Comment: I discovered that [node-proxy](https://github.com/samshull/node-proxy) (doesn't compile on Windows right now, grab `node-proxy.bin` from [here](http://blog.nowjs.com/running-nowjs-natively-on-windows)) DOES work on v 0.6.x WITHOUT any special command-line flags. However, you must return `true` from the `hasOwn` method on the proxy, not `getPropertyDescriptor`. Unfortunately, this means `if( (name in obj) )` checks will ALWAYS return true.

Answer (score 3):

There is no global missing member handler in javascript.  You'll need to introduce a function to abstract out the behavior

```
function getOrEmpty(obj, name) {
  if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    return "";
  }
  return obj[name];
}

var obj = {"foo":"bar"},
    arr = [];
arr.push(getOrEmpty(obj, "foo"));
arr.push(getOrEmpty(obj, "someUndefinedProperty"));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Right, but the code being run is user generated (from a template). Also, the `getOrEmpty` function would need to call `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, name)` instead of checking the value of the property itself against undefined. An `undefined` *value* may be intended.

Comment: p.s., I suggested using the prototype's `hasOwnProperty` instead of `obj`'s because if `obj` somehow gets a `hasOwnProperty` property the call will fail. I know in the example given this can't happen, but it is a good thing to watch out for.

Comment: @DavidMurdoch I figured that's why you suggested it. But if javascript code starts replacing predefined members you're essentially screwed anyways. No telling what they blew up.

Answer (score 2):

`Proxy.create` doesn't appear to be a thing anymore.

Here's a new example:

```js
const p = new Proxy({foo:1}, {
    get(obj, name) {
        return Object.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, name) ? obj[name] : '';
    }
})

console.log(p.foo);
console.log(p.bar);
```

You can [ab]use this to do fun little things like create React helpers:

```
const cc = new Proxy(Object.create(null), {
    get(proxy, name) {
        return ({className,...props}) => React.createElement(name, {className: classcat(className), ...props})
    }
})

<cc.tr className={[theme.tr,theme.hrow]}>...</cc.tr>
// renders: <tr class="datatable_tr--2vnM1 datatable_hrow--_PG2G">...</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

With ES6 and above you can use Proxy, like the accepted answer suggested. But here's an answer if you are stuck with ES5.

With ES5 you'll have to create your own class, like in this quick example

```
function StrictObject() {
  var values = Object.create(null);
  this.set = function (key, value) {
    values[key] = value;
  };
  this.get = function (key) {
    if (!(key in values)) {
      throw new Error("Could not find " + key);
    }
    return values[key];
  };
}
var obj = new StrictObject();

obj.set('dad', 'homer');
console.log(obj.get('dad'));    // homer
console.log(obj.get('uncle'));  // throws error
```