# Naming a method dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to name a method dynamically?

Let us say:

```
Class.prototype[name] = function(param) {
  console.log(name, param)
}
```

So if I do:

```
// will return `hello there`
class.hello('there')
// will return `hey there`
class.hey('there')
```

Is this possible to do?

---

I'm using the library [zerorpc](https://github.com/dotcloud/zerorpc-node).

They have a syntax of

```
client.invoke("iter", 10, 20, 2, function(error, res, more) {
```

So I want to create a class to wrap their function so I can do something like:

```
client.iter(10,20,2 function(...
```

---

This is how I tried:

```
var zerorpc = require('zerorpc')
var util  = require('util')
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter

var RPC = function () {
  if (!(this instanceof RPC)) return new RPC()

  this.rpc = new zerorpc.Client()
}

util.inherits(RPC, EventEmitter)
module.exports = RPC()

RPC.prototype.connect = function(config) {
  this.con = this.rpc.connect('tcp://' + config.host + ':' + config.port)
}

// this is the idea
RPC.prototype[name] = function(params) {
   this.rpc.invoke(name, params[0], params[1], params[2], function(error, res, more) { // ...
}
```

Saw this on gitbub [gist](https://gist.github.com/grimen/2840339).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: before calling method of object you need create this method, otherwise it will be `undefined`

Comment: You could do use Proxy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10744317/941764. However, browser support is limited to Firefox at this point: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: This is server side code. Not browser :)

Comment: Node has support for Proxy when you start it with the `--harmony` flag.

Comment: if you know all functions that you want use, then as workaround you can simply create it like: `['func1','func2',...].forEach(function(val){RPC.prototype[val] = function(params) {this.rpc.invoke(val,...)}})`

Comment: also in MDN [Non-standard Object.prototype.__noSuchMethod__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod)

Comment: @Grundy will this ever see a release with Node.JS? doesn't seem supported yet.

Comment: Interesting: https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=264

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)?

```
var obj = Proxy.create({
    get: function(target, value) {
        return function() {
            console.log('called ' + value)
        }
    }
});

obj.hello(); // "called hello"
obj.world(); // "called world"
```

You have to use `--harmony_proxies` option to enable proxies in node.

Comment: can I enable this by default when running node.js?

Comment: Saw this http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aproxies#simulating_nosuchmethod_doesnotunderstand

Comment: This is a possible answer but I don't like using experimental stuff and even having to invoke it explicitly when starting node. So Up for now.