# Adding new value to javascript associative array "on the fly" when trying to get value by not existing key

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

Is it possible to create and return new element of associative array "on the fly" when trying to get value by not existing key?

```
a = {};
a[5]; // return "fezzes"; a = {5: "fezzs"}
a[9]; // return "jtte";  a = {5: "fezzs", 9: "jtte"}
```

Comment: Something like this: `5 in a? a[5] : (a[5] = "fezzes")`

Comment: @CristianGreco That one is not a duplicate because in this case Philipp also wants to add the value to the list.

Comment: @lexicore you're right, the answer I linked is similar but still not complete for the use case of the OP. I removed my comment and updated my answer :)

Comment: @ChristianGreco Well done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to handle undefined object properties would be to use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object (and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10744317/1861412) answer has covers a similar use case):

```
a = { 1 : "hello" };

console.log(a[1]); //hello
console.log(a[2]); //undefined

var handler = {
    get: function(target, name){
        if (!(name in target)) {
            target[name] = "world";
        }
        return target[name];
    }
};

var p = new Proxy(a, handler);

console.log(a[1]); //hello
console.log(a[2]); //world
```

Proxies are a (nice) ES6 features. Firefox supports them since version 18, while in Chrome (and in Node.js) you have to enable the harmony flag.

Comment: You don't need to use Node.js. To enable ES6 features in Chrome just visit the internal url `chrome://flags/` and select `Enable Experimental JavaScript`.

Comment: @ФилиппЦветков btw, if you already know _which_ object properties could be accessed (but I don't think this is the case) you could define a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) on the object. Also note that I'm supposing you want to use the property accessors syntax (e.g. `a.b` or `a["b"]`) and not any wrapper method.

Answer (score 0):

you can create the object with custom getter method "getProp" like below, and you can access non existing keys as your wish, but make sure what is the default value you need on non existing keys

```
var t = Object.create({},{
                           getProp:{
                                     enumerable: false,
                                     value:function(a){
                                                        if(!this[a])this[a] =  'defaultValue'; 
                                                        return this[a];
                                   }
                          }
        });
```

out put

```
t.getProp('nonExistingKey') // return 'defaultValue', t return {'nonExistingKey': 'defaultValue'}
```