# Fire an error when Object property does not exists

Tags: javascript, object, properties, error-handling

Alias title: **Strict mode for object properties**

I'm working on a error manager and I want this to be very strict.
Suppose you are calling to a property that does not exist, this usually is interpreted as undefined, instead, it should throw an error, ex:

```
var obj = {};

obj.PI; //throw Error instead of undefined.
```

Result expected:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: obj.PI is not defined

I want to appear this error when we called any property that does not exist, should not necessarily be `PI`

Comment: You can use `use strict` either. It will work as you're wanting to.

Comment: `use strict` is just for global variables, but not for object properties

Comment: See [the ES6 proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) which provides a trap for all property access (get or set).  Also, [a related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727855/define-getter-on-object-so-all-undefined-property-lookups-return).

Comment: @jfriend00 unfortunately this is not supported on *Chrome Dev ES6*

Comment: @wZVanG - if you don't know the specific property in advance and can provide a getter for it to be able to intercept the request, then you're out of luck because until you get into ES6 features like the proxy, Javascript does not have the feature you're asking for.  In Javascript, referencing an undefined property is simply not an error.

Comment: What's an "error manager"? How does it work? Do you need to change the object definition, or would changing the property access work as well? Or are you looking for a global mode of the environment that you could enable (like strict mode) without altering the code?

Comment: @Bergi specifically I'm looking a method like `use strict` for object properties, ie: `"use strict"; var obj = {}; alert(obj.prop); //error`, I know that this method does not exist, but an alteration to Object (a getter method) is an approximate solution

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you know the specific properties you want to catch access to, then you can provide a getter for those properties and throw an error from the getter.

If you don't know the specific properties and want a catch-all for all undefined property access, then you will need [ES6 proxy support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) which is not widely available yet (appears to be in some versions of Firefox and in Microsoft Edge, but not in Chrome).  So, unless this is a Firefox or Edge-specific project, there is no support for what you're asking that is cross browser as this is not an ES5-level feature of Javascript.

FYI, with proxies, it would be the [`handler.get()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get)  that you would be interested in.

You can see the current level of ES6 proxy support here: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/